# Selected current date in form Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Don't have any idea when my app start in date form to be put the current date.I have a function when a day is clicked to be put in form, but how to do automatically, without clicking on it to be put there?

```
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    sclable: true,
    height: 355,
    contentHeight: 355,
    header: {
        right: 'details, today, prev,next',
    },
    dayClick: function (date) {
        var datePicker = date.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
        if (!dateToday) {
            $('#form_date').val(datePicker);
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to set the `form_date` input with the selected date from the calendar ? What is dateToday ? is the input type text or date ?

Comment: What do you mean automatically? If the user doesn't click the day, how will you know which day to put into the form?

Comment: @ADyson agreed, but I want the current day or any day to be put there, I mean, when the app starts the input field to not be empty, to have a day in it and then agreed, to change when the user picks a day.

Comment: ok well that's not related to fullcalendar then. If you just want the today's date to be in there when the page loads, then you can put `$('#form_date').val(moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY"));` somewhere at the start of your script.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for has more to do with HTML than with full-calendar.

You can achieve this by setting `value` attribute of your `<input />` tag.

```
<input id='calendar-input' />
```

There are two ways to get the seed value for your input field within your javascript code.

1.If you are using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), which is recommended with full-calendar, you can do something like this:

```
 const today = moment().format(#formatType);
    document.getElementById("calendar-input").value = today;
```

2.If  you want to use full-calendar's standard way of getting current date and set it accordingly, in which case it will work for both initial and subsequent selection use [getDate](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/getDate/) method. The method returns current date of the calendar and you can set it exactly like above instead of creating a new moment date object.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id='calendar-input' />
```

The above didn't work for me. try

```
<input type="date"/>
```